# Lowercase only the leftmost character of a string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have 2 columns containing strings. In the third column, I am trying to create a camelCase version of the strings, but I am stuck on how to accomplish the task. It has the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1&B1,"ñ","n")," del"," Del")," ","")
```

except that the leftmost character is in uppercase (like `BinanLaguna`).

All I know is the following formula makes a string lowercase, but I do not know how to return the entire string (`binanLaguna`) and not just the leftmost character (`b`):

```
=(LOWER(LEFT(C1,1)))
```

[image: LibreOffice camelcase problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your formula to change the case of the first letter, you can then get the rest of the string using `=MID(A1, 2, LEN(A1))`. This gets everything from the second letter to the end of the string in cell A1. You can then CONCATENATE the 2 values together.